# Как однозначно идентифицировать Button.inline кнопку Telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

В боте генерируются кнопки двух "типов" с разным, постоянно изменяющимся текстом, допустим:

```
type1 = [Button.inline(str(randint(0, 100)) for i in range(5)]
type2 = [Button.inline(str(randint(0, 100)) for i in range(5)]
await event.respond("Выберите кнопку", buttons=type1 + type2)
```

В **CallbackQuery()** приходит **event**, где я могу "подсмотреть" только **event.data**, содержащую текст кнопки (в вышеприведённом примере цифры).

Но как мне задать тип кнопки или добавить к ней дополнительной статичной информации?

Чтобы было примерно так:

```
Button.inline(text="ТЕКСТ", type=0)
```

или

```
Button.inline(text="ТЕКСТ", type=1)
```

...и в CallbackQuery я мог бы отличить одну группу кнопок от другой вне зависимости от значений текста или данных?

Покорнейше благодарю за советы!

**UPD.**
Решил так. К тексту каждой кнопки дописываю символы, получается, например:
"1", "3", "2", "1", "3"

Теперь, проверяя первый символ, могу определить "тип" или "группу" кнопки. Но это колхоз конечно же. Хочется более адекватного решения

Comment: Там вроде есть что-то вроде `callback_data`

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ натолкнул на мысль :)